# Javascript callback confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I am using DataTables to display row data, in the last column on the right have have 2 images, one for edit and one for delete.  In order to trap the click event I use:

```
 $('#datatable tbody tr a.delete img').live( 'click', function () {
        });
```

A friend  gave me this code to try..

```
function fancyAlert(msg) {
        jQuery.fancybox({
        'modal' : true,
        'content' : "<div style=\"margin:1px;width:240px;\">"+msg+"<div style=\"text-align:right;margin-top:10px;\"><input style=\"margin:3px;padding:0px;\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"jQuery.fancybox.close();\" value=\"Ok\"></div></div>"
        });
    }

    function fancyConfirm(msg,callback) {
        var ret;
        jQuery.fancybox({
            modal : true,
            content : "<div style=\"margin:1px;width:240px;\">"+msg+"<div style=\"text-align:right;margin-top:10px;\"><input id=\"fancyConfirm_cancel\" style=\"margin:3px;padding:0px;\" type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\"><input id=\"fancyConfirm_ok\" style=\"margin:3px;padding:0px;\" type=\"button\" value=\"Ok\"></div></div>",
            onComplete : function() {
                jQuery("#fancyConfirm_cancel").click(function() {
                    ret = false;
                    jQuery.fancybox.close();
                })
                jQuery("#fancyConfirm_ok").click(function() {
                    ret = true;
                    jQuery.fancybox.close();
                })
            },
            onClosed : function() {
                callback.call(this,ret);
            }
        });
    }

    function fancyConfirm_text() {
        fancyConfirm("Ceci est un test", function(ret) {
        alert(ret)
        })
    }
```

Which works when I use it like:

```
$('#datatable tbody tr a.delete img').live( 'click', function () {

     if (!fancyConfirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?"))
            e.preventDefault();

 });
```

I am confused about the callback part because when I click "Cancel" the box goes away but the page is still grayed out and locked.  What I want to do is if the user clicks cancel to end and go back to normal and if the user clicks "Ok" then I need to pass var rowID to  a file "delete_row.php"...  But this is new territory for me..  If it was a simple html link I can get the .val and be done but in DataTables I don't have that option..

Can anyone here point me in the right direction?  I've googled this to death but am unable to find information on my usage requirements.

Comment: What do you have in your href of the anchor tag?

Comment: While I don't have time to help you I just wanted to point out that there's no need to excuse yourself. We're all here to help all coders of all levels of experience. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fancyConfirm` function is expecting callback function, when not given there is error in the fancybox `onclosed` event which might explain why it stay gray.

Try changing the call to:

```
fancyConfirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", function(ret) { })
```

Comment: That worked! thanks..  and I understand what I was missing so its a double bonus..  :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know I needed to do that till just now.. lol  Thanks again!

Comment: @Dennis no problem, that's how this place works - glad you also accepted answers on your other questions. :)